# Any efficient way to determine there is more N continuous true in a boolean array? In Java

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

Example:

I have a boolean array with N boolean inside. Which is the most efficient way to determine there are more than continuous M true flags, in the array?

Write some thing like (bA=booleanArray, for M=3)

```
(bA[0] && bA[1] && bA[2]) || (bA[1] && bA[2] && bA[3]) || ...
```

is really ugly.

And this can not be done with a VERY-LONG dynamic length array with dynamic least true flags to meet need. And maybe inefficient with few and scattered true?

Comment: keep a count variable and just forloop through it. Then if that count = something you return true or w.e.

Comment: what is inefficient about the above?

Comment: Use a loop and a counter.

Comment: imo a one-liner like the above looks cleaner than a loop and an external variable. What's so bad about it?

Comment: @MitchWeaver, I am going to assume the title of the question is indicative of the problem where *N* is not specified, and the length of the array is not fixed. As a result, the example of the three continuous true statements cannot be easily generalized. If the question is constrained to 6 booleans and looking for 3, then perhaps the one line code is appropriate, but it is not generally applicable.

Comment: @KevinO + Thilo ...No sane person would have a condition check for a array of a 1000. **edit**: didn't see OP edited his question

Comment: @MitchWeaver Agree with you fully, but the OP has now changed his question, so of course if it is dynamic then a loop is the only way to go.

Comment: This is, in fact, the most efficient way to do it. I entered the condition into Karnaugh map optimizer, and got your expression back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a loop and a counter:

```
int count = 0;
for (boolean x: theArray){
   if (x) {
       count++;
       if (count >= n) return true;  // n is the count we are looking for
   } else { count = 0; }
}
return false;
```

Comment: at least explain why it works. don't post code with no explanation

Comment: it works by iterating over the array, increasing a counter for every true met, resetting the counter when the chain of trues is broken, concluding when the counter reaches 3. Sorry if that was not obvious.

Comment: I know how it works. I just think pasting code with no explanation to the asker is bad form. Not very helpful for learning, and VERY unhelpful for those who come to this question later.

Answer (score 3):

This is one approach, that allows for adjusting the number of consecutive entries, and the array is not fixed in length. The method `hasConsecutiveTrue` will loop over the array, looking for a value of `true`. If found, it increments the counter, otherwise sets it to 0. If the counter matches the expected amount, it returns true. Otherwise, it will return false.  **EDIT:** based upon a comment, make so it will throw an IllegalArgumentException for an attempt to find <= 0 consecutive numbers, or if the input array is null/empty.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int consecutive = 3;
    boolean[] ba = new boolean[] { true, false, true, true, true, false};


    System.out.println("found: " + hasConsecutiveTrue(ba, consecutive));
}

private static boolean hasConsecutiveTrue(boolean[] ba, int consecutive) throws IllegalArgumentException
{
    // we will not attempt to process if the input <= 0; if 0 should return
    // true, then modify the conditional statement as appropriate
    if (consecutive <= 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input for consecutive: " +
         consecutive);
    }

    if (ba == null || ba.length < 1) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("No array to check!");
    }

    int count = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    for (boolean b : ba) {
        count = ( b ? count + 1 : 0);
        if (count == consecutive) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return found;
}
```

Comment: this will fail if some idiot passed in `0` for the `consecutive` value

Comment: @ScaryWombat, a good point, and defensive programming should probably account for `<=0` as an invalid input. I wonder if `0` is a special case that is always true? I will edit to throw IllegalArgumentException for `<=0`, but others may have different requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one using `BitSet`: if you're able to start with a BitSet, it will almost certainly be more efficient. If you have to convert from a `boolean[]` or `byte[]`, it might not be.

```
// BitSet bits = BitSet.valueOf(bA);
int i = bits.nextSetBit(0);
while (i > -1 && i < bits.length()) {
  int nextFalse = bits.nextClearBit(i);
  if (nextFalse - nextTrue > N) return true;
  i = bits.nextSetBit(nextFalse) + 1;
}
return false;
```

Comment: Hmm. Why would this be more efficient? I can see it maybe using less memory, but performance-wise the primitive array should win out.

Comment: It uses a primitive array in rt.jar.  And if your rt.jar uses native code for `BitSet`'s bit handling, then it will possibly win out.

Comment: interesting, is nextSetBit more quicker than iterating over an array?

Comment: Depends on how it's implemented :) Certainly there will be fewer loops in user code with this solution. There may be the same number of loops overall, depending on how `nextClearBit` and `nextSetBit` are implemented.

Comment: Just added a minor optimization: can eliminate a couple of loops with the `+1` in `nextSetBit` inside the loop.

Comment: Just read my ORACLE JDK 1.8.0_72 code(windows 64bit), sadly found it's just an ordinary arraylist like, not native. Some index check, then every bit back up by a part of long(how sad...), then some trailing method.

Comment: no offense, is there really a native implementation of BitSet? i google and found nothing.

Comment: You may need to pay for a more expensive JDK ;) If speed is imperative, you'll have to do testing. Depending on how long your arrays are, how bit N is, etc., you may find that something off-the-wall may be faster. Like and-ing with pre-built longs full of N-long 1s (e.g. for array = 16 bits, N = 3, you could use 1110111011101110 and 0111011101110111 and 0011101110111000 and 0001110111011100). Exactly how that would work is beyond my simple brain, though...

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a string with T + F in the location to determine the true/false setting of your array. Then use contains.

Example:

```
String booleanArray = "TTFFTFTFTFTTTFFT";
if ( !booleanArray.contains("TTT") ) // Pattern was found.
```